# gSOAP C union to xml encoding

Tags: c, xml, gsoap

I am generating the C to XML encoders using the soapcpp2 tool from gSoap 2.8.44
My input to soapcpp2 is an h file with:

```
union U_u
{
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
};

struct A_t {
        int choice_type;
        int __union_choice_type;
        union U_u choice;
};
```

After running the soapcpp2 -c and after linking with my test code, I get the encoded xml as

```
<A-t>
   <choice-type>1</choice-type>
   <i>0</i>
</A-t>
```

Why is the union element name missing from the xml? 
I was expecting this:

```
<A-t>
    <choice-type>1</choice-type>
    <choice>
      <i>0</i>
    </choice>
</A-t>
```

Is there an option to include the union name also in the xml?

Answer (score 0):

A union provides a choice of elements, so one of `<i>`, `<j>`, or `<k>` will show up in XML.

If you want these to be subelements of `<choice>` then use:

```
struct A_t {
    int choice_type;
    struct A_t_choice {
        int __union_choice_type;
        union U_u choice;
    } choice;
};
```